# Resolving relative paths with an alias in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm developing my first React-Native app and I'm trying to set up some kind of aliases for local path, to avoid complicated dependencies such as

`import {module} from "../../../other/module/"`

I'm essentially looking for something similar to Webpack's [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) option.

The solutions I've found online don't seem to work with the latest version of react-native, including using `babel-plugin-module-resolver`. (I'm developing a web version that uses `react-native-web`, the plugin worked for that one but not for the iOS simulator, and it eventually broke on the web version too, I'm not sure why).

My gut feeling is that there must be a way of configuring the m[etro-bundler](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler), but so far I'm not finding any documentation about that.

What are your solutions for this? Or do you just use relative paths?

Comment: There is definitely a solution to this. Trying to remember what it was or where I saw it, but I know it exists. (think, Chris...think!!!)

Comment: @ChrisGeirman any update? Or did you stop worrying about it?

Comment: It's called an import path resolver https://moduscreate.com/blog/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/

Comment: ??? Isn't that webpack?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032522/eslint-complains-about-typescripts-path-aliasing

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file named `package.json` in each folder that you want to make alias, and inside this file write the name of alias like below(for example inside folder 'other'):

```
{
    "name": "other"
}
```

now you can import everything inside other with `other` alias from anywhere within your project

```
import {module} from "other/module/"
```