# eslint complains about typescript's path aliasing

Tags: typescript, eslint

I've set up path aliasing in typescript's `.tsconfig` so my imports look cleaner.

In my code when I try and import my interface like this

```
import { ApiResponse } from '@api';
```

eslint complains: `Unable to resolve path to module '@api'`
However, intelisense in vscode seems fine. Its able to give code prediction and "Jump to declaration" which is a clue that my `.tsconfig` is set up correctly but eslint is somehow misconfigured.

---

### Relevant files

In my **tsconfig.json**, I've set up path aliasing like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",               
    "baseUrl": "./src",                     
    "paths": {                              
      "@api": ["./types/api"]
    },
  }
}
```

My **./src/types/api.ts** looks like this:

```
// 3rd party API response object
export interface ApiResponse {
  ....
}
```

Finally, my **.eslintrc.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "console": true
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".ts"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Add `paths: ['./src']` to `"import/resolver"` inside your `.eslintrc.js`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

To support the tsconfig `baseUrl` and `paths`, you need the package [`eslint-import-resolver-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

1. Make sure to have the basics:

```sh
# install the basics
npm i -D @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

# support tsconfig baseUrl and paths
npm i -D eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

2. Then in the eslintrc, here in json:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "tsconfigRootDir": "./"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any chance you know how this maps to an `.eslintrc.js` file?

Comment: Using small snippet: module.exports = { ..., plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'], ... }

Comment: This is not working for me...

Comment: if this does not work, try these:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699452/5598783
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069522/5598783

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem, and it was trickier since I am using a monorepo structure.
resolved that by using [`eslint-import-resolver-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

As explained in the doc, inside your eslint config, you add this configuration pointing to all your projects.

```
// inside .eslintrc

"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "typescript": {
      // use an array
      "project": [
        "packages/module-a/tsconfig.json",
        "packages/module-b/tsconfig.json"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: omg. thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for. I also have a monorepo of AWS Lambda functions. Even a wildcard `"packages/*/tsconfig.json"` worked for me.

Comment: life saver. added my package to the project array and it worked instantly. ty!

Comment: I simply added `packages/tsconfig.json` in the projects object, and it worked!

Answer (score 6):

I have created react native project with typescript enabled using expo. I have followed the below steps to add path aliasing

**folder structure:**

[image: folder structure]

**Steps:**

1. Add baseURL and custom paths in tsconfig.json under compilerOptions as follow:

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
            "jsx": "react-native",
            "lib": [
            "dom",
            "esnext"
            ],
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "noEmit": true,
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "resolveJsonModule": true,
            "strict": true,
            "baseUrl": ".",
            "paths": {
              "*": ["src/*"],
              "$utility/*": ["src/utility/*"], // if /* is not added eslint throwing error so should be added in name and path as well
              "$themes/*": ["./src/themes/*"],
              "$assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"]
            }
        }
   ```
2. Add aliases in babel.config.js under 'module-resolver' as follow:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            [
                'module-resolver',
                {
                    root: ["./src"],
                    alias: {
                        "$utility": './src/utility',
                        "$themes": './src/themes',
                        "$assets": './src/assets',
                    },
                },
            ],
        ],
    };
};
```

3. Install eslint-plugin-import & eslint-import-resolver-typescript using following command:
   `npm i -D eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-typescript`
4. After installing packages add typescript under import/resolver as below in eslintrc file:

   ```
          "settings": {
            "import/core-modules": ["@expo/vector-icons"],
            "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
            "import/parsers": {
              "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
            },
            "import/resolver": {
              "typescript": {},
              "node": {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
              }
            }
        }
   ```
5. Refresh vscode using command + shift + p -> Reload window.

**Note:** Projects created using expo will have babel-plugin-module-resolver package installed by default so no need to install it again

Comment: not working with nextjs typescript eslint

Answer (score 0):

My project is an electron app set up using the electron forge webpack-typescript template, I also added React to the project. I fixed this issue by:

- adding `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` as a dev dependency
- updating `.eslintrc.json` to include:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
}
```