# Using relative paths with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to import Module using relative path in react-native , my project structure is like this :

```
-Project
--Components
--- adapter.js
--src
---screen
----Main.js
--App.js
```

I want to use adapter.js in my Main.js  , so in the `Main.js` i use : `import adapter from '/../Components/adapter'`

this will throw the following error :

> Module not found: Can't resolve '/../Components/adapter' in
> 'E:\reactjs\learn\Project\src\screens'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032522/eslint-complains-about-typescripts-path-aliasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file `Main.js` is inside `src/screen` and `adapter.js` is inside `Components`, you need to go two levels down from `Main.js` to get out of `screen`, `src` and then enter `Components`.

You will end up with something like `../../Components/adapter`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver, it's a good module to have alias with import.

You have to specify a babel.config.js in React Native and a configuration:

```
  module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          components: './src/components',
          _main: './src/components/_main',
          screens: './src/screens',
          config: './src/config',
          navigations: './src/navigations',
          utils: './src/utils',
          actions: './src/state/actions',
          constants: './src/state/constants',
          contexts: './src/state/contexts',
          reducers: './src/state/reducers',
          assets: './src/assets/',
          hooks: './src/hooks',
          data: './src/data',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

And after, you can import your module like this :

```
import HomeFeed from 'components/Home';
```

Answer (score 5):

Note: that VSCode will detect the import

You need to add a `tsconfig.js` file

The next line

```
"baseUrl": "src"
```