# Typescript paths working correctly, but eslint is not respecting them

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc

After looking through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032522/eslint-complains-about-typescripts-path-aliasing) post and trying everything in here. Nothing seemed to work.

We tried adding the node part to the import/resolver but that did not seem to work. We are also u sing a monorepo if that effects anything? Something else that was tried was adding a `project` to the typescript resolver but that also did not work.

Tried switching up the paths to the direct path inside the tsconfig.json, but that also did not work.

Here are my files:

Example import: `import { colors } from "@styles"`

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "@styles": ["src/styles/index.ts"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "stories/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

`.eslintrc.js`:

```js
const vars = ["const", "let", "var"]

module.exports = {
  plugins: ["graphql"],
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect"
    },
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/resolvers": {
      typescript: {}
    }
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },
  rules: {
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "newlines-between": "never"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain": "off",
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        prev: vars,
        next: "*"
      },
      {
        blankLine: "any",
        prev: vars,
        next: vars
      },
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        prev: "*",
        next: "return"
      },
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        prev: "*",
        next: "block-like"
      },
      {
        blankLine: "always",
        prev: "block-like",
        next: "*"
      }
    ],
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "no-irregular-whitespace": "off"
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.js", "*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      rules: {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eslint complains about typescript's path aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032522/eslint-complains-about-typescripts-path-aliasing)

Comment: @spender it did not, in fact it broke other things by adding some of the code that was recommended haha.

Comment: What file extension are the files you are scanning with eslint?