# Setting up eslint-import-resolver-typescript in monorepo

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm trying to add [path-mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to a monorepo. I already have [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.24.2/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md) rules in place, and I'm getting an error "Unable to resolve path to module" on all mapped imports.

```
app/
├─ package/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
.eslintrc
tsconfig.json
```

.eslintrc looks like

```json
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The inner tsconfig.json looks like:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "actions/*": ["src/actions/*"],
      "context/*": ["src/context/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The paths map just fine, but I have the lint error "Unable to resolve path to module 'context' wherever I try to use the mapped path.

Researching this shows I need to use the [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript) package, but it hasn't made the errors go away.

Answer (score 6):

This is the lint settings that ended up working:

```json
"settings": {
  "import/parsers": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
  },
  "import/resolver": {
    "typescript": {
      "project": ["tsconfig.json", "package/tsconfig.json"]
    },
    "node": {
      "project": ["tsconfig.json", "package/tsconfig.json"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not positive the node settings are needed. There is more conversation on the [import-js github page](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2301).

Comment: Important is the `"plugins": ["import"]` part as described in their docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript?activeTab=readme). And ensure to restart the eslint server (restart IDE) after changing configs.

Comment: +1 helped me with a monorepo project
"typescript": {
      "project": ["tsconfig.json", "package/tsconfig.json"]
    }" references the project tsconfig, and a submodule tsconfig. Thanks!